Strict aliasing of first struct member through opaque pointer in C
Consider the following ISO C code:
struct S {
    int a;
};

void f() {
    struct S s;
    *(int*)&s = 1;  // 1
    ((struct S*)(struct Opaque*)&s)->a = 2;  // 2
    *(int*)(struct Opaque*)&s = 3;  // 3
}

Does this code contain any undefined behavior?
My own understanding is:

Statement 1 does not trigger undefined behavior because of C17 §6.7.2.15 "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member and vice versa"
Statement 2 does not trigger undefined behavior, despite the casts, because we are accessing the object through its effective type S, therefore it does not violate the strict aliasing rule (C17 §6.5.7)
But what about statement 3? Opaque is not defined as having a first member of type int, so it seems that 6.7.2.15 does not apply (the unclear meaning of "suitably converted" tends to muddy the waters here). And the strict aliasing rule does not seem to allow accessing an object of effective type S through an int pointer (though it does allow the reverse). So, is statement 3 undefined behavior or not?


This cannot be properly language-lawyered because the C standard does not define “suitably converted.” The aliasing rules are concerned only with the type used for access; intermediate pointer conversions are irrelevant. And there is an int at the desired address. So the only question is whether the desired pointer value survives the conversions.

@EricPostpischil: Given void *p=something(); struct s1 { int arr[i]; } *p1=p; struct s2 { int arr[3]; }; *p2=p, could the expressions p1->arr[0] and p2->arr[0] be used to access arbitrary objects of type int, given that (p1->arr+0) and (p2->arr+0) are both expressions of type int*, or would the intermediate pointer types struct s1* an struct s2* be involved in aliasing analysis?

Re: "suitably converted": I keep wondering what does it mean exactly. In other words: what's the exact definition / rules of "suitably converted". @EricPostpischil Doesn't the C standard define “suitably converted” on purpose or is it a defect (perhaps there is a DR)?


Statement 1 does not trigger undefined behavior because of C17 §6.7.2.15 "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member and vice versa"

That is the only sensible interpretation of the standard indeed - an explicit cast to the type of the first member with the correct qualifiers, if any. As per 6.5 a struct pointer may also alias with a pointer to a member contained in that struct.


Statement 2 does not trigger undefined behavior, despite the casts, because we are accessing the object through its effective type S

Not necessarily. C17 6.3.2.3 says:

A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

This is allowed to fail during the (struct Opaque*)&s pointer conversion itself. It's somewhat unlikely to happen in practice, but possible in theory.
Other than that, (struct S*) ... ->a equals a lvalue access with the same effective type struct S as the object was declared with, so that part is well-defined.


But what about statement 3?

Same thing here, the pointer conversions aren't necessarily well-defined.
Apart from that, it isn't sensible to say that an aggregate cannot be accessed through the element/member type of that aggregate. One big flaw in the strict aliasing rules is that they indeed don't mention what effective type an aggregate (or union) has, nor what happens with qualifiers in terms of effective type. Is int arr[5]; one object of effective type int [5] or 5 objects of effective type int? It isn't specified explicitly so nobody knows. It becomes a "quality of implementation" thing.
Consider struct S* s = malloc(sizeof *s); s->a = 1;. Or int* a = malloc(int[n]); a[0] = 1;. malloc returns a pointer to an object with no effective type. It won't get one until the first lvalue write access. In both of my examples we access a member/array item of type int. If that means that the type of that memory location is now a scalar int and not an aggregate struct/array, the whole C language comes crumbling down. Because then for example a[1] = 1; would suddenly be an out-of-bounds access of the scalar. Which would be ridiculous.
The only help we have from the C language here is 7.22.3 which says that the memory returned must be usable as an array (but structs/unions are not mentioned). This rule is not harmonized with the concept of effective type however.
So the answer is: nobody knows. The language standard is unhelpful and unclear here.

The Standard was written in an era before compiler writers started using language lawyers to justify useless behavior, and as such it fails to define its terminology in an unambiguous manner that can withstand language-lawyering.  Further, when C89 it was written, it was well recognized and accepted that if a compiler could have to generate code without having to know or care about how a type was defined, the definition of the type (or non-existence of any such definition) should be irrelevant to the functioning of the code.  If a type could exist which would require a piece of code to behave in some particular defined way, and no type could exist that would require the code to behave differently, then the code would have been expected to behave as it would if some suitable type happened to exist somewhere in the universe..
On the other hand, there are situations on some popular platforms where the behavior of code that converts a pointer through a pointer to a structure or union type may be affected by the alignment requirement of the latter type.
As processed by clang, this can even happen with unions which never accessed using the types with coarser alignments.  Consider, for example:
#include <string.h>
struct s1 { unsigned arr; };
struct s2 { unsigned char s[sizeof (struct s1)]; };
void test(void *dest, void *src)
{
  memcpy((struct s1*)dest, (struct s1*)src, sizeof (struct s1));
}

The code clang generates for the ARM Cortex-M0 will fail if p isn't 32-bit aligned, even when using -fno-strict-aliasing.  Such potential behavioral differences for different structure types wouldn't seem like they should matter in cases where there isn't any definition for a type, but when using "Whole Program Optimization" a compiler might interpret the lack of any definition of a structure that would require it to work with pointers of arbitrary alignment as justifying an assumption that pointers converted to that type will satisfy even the coarsest possible alignment requirements.
The Standard doesn't delve into the effects of applying multiple conversions to a pointer because the authors wanted neither to imply that all compilers must attach semantic significance to intermediate conversions, nor to imply that a compiler given an expression like *(unsigned*)floatPtr should ignore the type of floatPtr in deciding whether that expression might access storage which is used by an object of type float.  Unfortunately, some compiler writers are less interested in what they would need to do to process programs usefully than in finding excuses not to do so, and interpret the Standard's lack of specificity as an invitation to behave nonsensically.

We're talking about C17, and I think the "language lawyering" you decry was common well before 2017.

@NateEldredge: Has anything relevant to the question changed between C99 and C17?  Nothing in C89 suggested that the behavior of structPtr->member shouldn't be agnostic to everything but the existence, type, and offset of the named member within structPtr's type, nor that (struct s2*)(struct s1*)structPtr and (void*)(struct s1*)structPtr shouldn't both be agnostic to the definition of struct s1; while C89 did't expressly specify such equivalence in all cases where it should apply, the equivalence applied globally in the language the Standard was chartered to describe, and...

...nothing in C89 or the published Rationale therefor suggested any intention to change that.  C99 deliberately gave implementations permission to deviate from those equivalences, without making any systematic effort to identify all of the places where they should hold.  While the OP's exact code didn't pose any alignment issues, such issues could easily arise in similar code, especially if one casts pointers to union types in an effort to get around code-breaking interpretations of type-based-aliasing rules.  Do you not view the alignment issues as relevant?
